# Can my hooked uninstall class function access a global var declared in main plugin file?

Tags: plugins, hooks, uninstallation

My current setup is as follows...

In the main plugin file, these two hooks are set (not inside any class):

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('DG_Setup', 'activation'));
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, array('DG_Setup', 'uninstall'));
```

This same main file includes the file containing `DG_Setup`:

```
include_once DG_PATH . 'inc/class-setup.php';
```

And declares `$dg_options`:

```
define('DG_OPTION_NAME', 'document_gallery');
$dg_options = get_option(DG_OPTION_NAME);
```

I assumed that by referencing the main plugin file for the hook, all the setup within would run before my uninstall hook was executed, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

In this same file, a number of declarations and variables are setup. When the uninstall hook fires, it doesn't seem to have access to any of the declared values or to the variable. I have tried explicitly including the main plugin file within the uninstall hook, but that doesn't change anything.

```
class DG_Setup {
   public static function uninstall() {
      if (!current_user_can('activate_plugins')) return;
      check_admin_referer('bulk-plugins');

      include_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'class-thumber.php';

      $options = DG_Thumber::getOptions();
      var_dump($options); // null

      foreach ($options['thumbs'] as $val) {
         if (false !== $val) {
            @unlink($val['thumb_path']);
         }
      }

      delete_option(DG_OPTION_NAME);
   }
}

class DG_Thumber {
   public static function getOptions() {
      include_once plugin_dir_path(dirname(__FILE__)) . 'document-gallery.php';

      global $dg_options;
      return $dg_options['thumber'];
   }
}
```

Obviously I could just re-declare all of theses values, but then I'm declaring the same value in multiple places which is very [un-DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). So my question is, how can I handle this *cleanly*?

Comment: Where is the `$dg_options` global set? If it is created by a function hooked to an action like `'init'`, it won't get called. (`'init'` is happens before the uninstall hook is run.)

Comment: @J.D. `$dg_options` is declared in the main body of the main plugin file, prior to including the file with `DG_Setup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't declaring `$dg_options` as global here:

```
define('DG_OPTION_NAME', 'document_gallery');
$dg_options = get_option(DG_OPTION_NAME);
```

During uninstall you aren't in the global scope, your file is being included by `uninstall_plugin()`.

So you need to add this at the top of the main plugin file:

```
global $dg_options;
```

Really, any time you want a variable to be global, you should be sure to use the `global` statement. Don't take scope for granted.

Comment: That did the trick. Didn't consider that it could end up in a function scope when called.